# Сертификат удаленной стороны до начала обмена данными

Tags: golang, ssl

Делаю пробный код сервера:
https://gist.github.com/rekby/201588f226de4d00a35a

Код клиента:
https://gist.github.com/rekby/348b0e2faac09ccb6477

В выводе получаю:

```
START
OK  [::1]:54323
TLS
[]
[2]
TLS
tmpClient
```

т.е. первый раз, когда вывожу сертификаты - список сертификатов пуст, затем читаю из соединения 1 байт и получаю доступ к сертификату.

Почему так происходит и можно ли получить доступ к сертификату клиента до прочтения первого байта (как обходной путь я конечно могу просто 0 слать первым байтом и его читать, но хотелось бы понять причину).

P.S. публикация сертификатов и ключей в данном случае не страшна - они временные, только для этого эксперимента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что до *рукопожатия* ничего не произойдёт. Иными словами метод `tls#Conn.Read` ровно как и `Write` вызывают *рукопожатие* автоматически. Иначе нужно вызвать его вручную. Вот собственно метод [tls#Conn.Handshake](http://godoc.org/crypto/tls#Conn.Handshake).
А вот его описание:

> Handshake runs the client or server handshake protocol if it has not yet been run. Most uses of this package need not call Handshake explicitly: the first Read or Write will call it automatically.

К делу. В Вашем сервере достаточно просто вызвать `tlsconn.Handshake()` перед работой со структурой (или работать со структурой после вызова методов `Read`/`Write`).

```
    // строка 122
    }

    tlsconn.Handshake()

    fmt.Println("TLS")
    fmt.Println(tlsconn.ConnectionState().PeerCertificates[0].Subject.CommonName)

    nullBuf := []byte{1}
    // продолжение
```

[golang](/questions/tagged/golang) [tls](/questions/tagged/tls)